# Consumir OSB desde .NET C#

Tags: webservice, soap, wsdl, .asmx

Existen unos servicios web creados con jDeveloper (Desconozco el código) y subidos a Oracle Service BUS.

Necesito orientación de como consumir uno de estos servicios en una aplicación Web MVC C#.
Los tutoriales que encuentro consideran los servicios con URL con terminación .asmx
y el servicio que crea el OSB es de terminación ?wsdl

Y en este ámbito no he encontrado información precisa.

Acaso no se puede ? y necesito un intermediario que transforme el servicio ?

Comment: Necesitas la documentación de esos servicios

Comment: Visual studio te permite agregar una referencia web o una referencia de servicio, si no me equivoco en todo ese proceso el visual studio siempre usa el wsdl, no importa que la url termine en .asmx al final de forma automatica queda .asmx?wsdl. Asi que si ya tienes el wsdl del servicio OSB solo debes de seguir los mismo pasos de los tutoriales que encontraste.

Comment: Aqui tienes un asmx: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx

Comment: Y para obtener el wsdl del asmx seria: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL

Comment: Como te comente arriba si ya tienes el wsdl del OSB solo sigue los mismo pasos de los tutoriales que encontraste o leeiste.

Comment: Encontré una forma de leer el servicio, sin importar nada en el VS2010 ([https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-web-service-using-soap-request/](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-web-service-using-soap-request/)). Este guarda la respuesta http en un *streamreader*, luego puedo visualizar los datos pero sin ningún tipo de formato. Trato de leerlo con un XmlReader ahora